# I'm getting an error in Jupyter Notebook using R

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I'm using R on Jupyter Notebook to complete a Cousera Assignment (Analysis of Global COVID-19 Pandemic Data). Despite following a detailed tutorial, I still get error messages that my variables are not defined, even after defining it properly.

In the attached image, I used the following code:

wiki_base_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php"
response <- GET(wiki_base_url)
response

```
wiki_base_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php"
response <- GET(wiki_base_url)
response
```

Yet, I got an error that says:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 2>()
  1 # Call the get_wiki_covid19_page function and print the response
   ----> 2 wiki_base_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php"
 3 response <- GET(wiki_base_url)
   4 response
  NameError: name 'wiki_base_url' is not defined
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iidXn.png)

Comment: Why have you tagged [tag:python]?

Comment: That error doesn't look like an R error message. Are you sure you've selected an R kernel for the code in the notebook? It looks like your notebook thinks that is a python code chunk.

Comment: As MrFlick suggested, you aren't using the right kernel. In the image you included, you can clearly see in the upper right side that it says `Python 3 (ipykernel)` kernel.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I tagged python because it seemed similar to what I was doing. This is my first posting a qiuestion, my bad.

Comment: @MrFlick, I honestly haven't figured out the right kernel for R even after downloading different R packages. I later resort to using Rstudio where I was able to overcome the error.

Comment: @Wayne, thanks very much. I noticed that too. Apparently, I'm new to this so I'm still figuring out a lot of things.

Comment: @Coolshegs. I can point you at an example of running the R kernel in Jupyter at http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r/master?filepath=index.ipynb . Click that and when the session spins up (you'll finally see Jupyter - just refresh if it says failed to connect to stream), you'll notice the kernel is `R` in the upper right and you'll see R code in the cells. Run those cells and you'll see R process the code. It works because the kernel installed and chosen is `IRkernel`. See [here](https://kyleake.medium.com/how-to-install-r-in-jupyter-with-irkernel-in-3-steps-917519326e41) ...

Comment: <continued> ... or [here](https://richpauloo.github.io/2018-05-16-Installing-the-R-kernel-in-Jupyter-Lab/). Those resources are old so things may not look quite like those. But they should give you an idea of how to do things so you can get it working in your own Jupyter. You could also keep using [the online R in Jupyter in your browser I pointed you at(served by MyBinder)](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r/master?filepath=index.ipynb), just keep in mind it is temporary and will disconnect if inactive or times out after a while. So save back to your own machine often.

Comment: @Wayne thanks so so much. I'll check out all the resources you listed and give you a feedback.

Comment: @Wayne thanks very much. I later got how to install the R kernel, but I got the error below when I tried to install the necessary packages.

("installation of package 'GET' had non-zero exit status")

Comment: You aren't saying what command triggered that error. Plus it looks like it would be a subject of another post.

Comment: @Wayne Oh sorry. I was trying to install all the necessary packages, especially "GET" package which had other dependeries. 

I used the command "install.packages('GET')"

Comment: That error, 'installation of package 'GET' had non-zero exit status", doesn't look like an R error? Exactly where are you running it? I may be wrong because I'm not able to reproduce it because running that in the R kernel or in RStudio seems to work.

Comment: @Wayne I think its actually an R error. I ran it in Jupyter Notebook under the R kernel. I was able to install other packages like;

_install.packages(c('rvest', 'httr','GET'))_

It executed for "rvest", and "httr", but gave me the error response, _"installation of package 'GET' had non-zero exit status"_

Comment: Oh okay. I get why you say that now. That package name is pretty much un-Googlable for help. I think though it is a question for another post. You answered your original question and know that you can install packages in the notebook because the other commands worked for installing `rvest` and `httr`.

Comment: @Wayne yes sir, I already solved the major issue (being unable to run R commands in Jupyter) through this thread and I'm very grateful for all your contributions. 

I already made a lot of searches on Youtube and Google, but couldn't fix it. It's quite unfortunate that I can't complete the projects on my professional course, "Introduction to R Programming for Data Science" on Cousera due to these packages that didn't install. 

I guess I'll have to make another post concering that and hopefully, get a professional assistance. Thanks very much once again sir.

Comment: Keep in mind, I said that the installation of GET worked at the MyBinder site I linked. You couldn't work there and save your work back to local when done? (Save often as the sessions are temporary and time out after inactivity, too.)

Comment: @Wayne thanks very much sir, I tried using the link but I just couldn't figure it out. 

Firstly, the packages I'll need for the project didn't install and even when I tried to add new tabs to my own codes, it didn't execute at all. So sorry to bother you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the three packages you listed worked and installed. But if there's a lot of other packages or content you need, then it may not help you. There's usually TAs for coursera courses. They cannot help you by providing a place in the cloud where the system works? Or guidance how to sort out your installation of GET?

Comment: @Wayne Of course, I posted on the discussion group, a staff replied and advised that I complete the assignement in the recommended "SN lab environment". Luckily, I was able to install "GET" package, but got stuck later when I couldn't install other packages that I need to visualize the extracted data. Suprisingly, the staff refused to reply and I just couldn't find "reply" button anymore in the thread. Seems he marked it as "Solved". Back to square 1.